# Reminders won't sync

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sync, phone, evernote

been using the app "Reminders" and it was working (albeit poorly). I tired to use it on 25/04/15 and I kept getting message "unknown error connecting to evernote" I can still view older notes on my phone (BQ Aquaris E4.5) but it won't sync any new notes. I can also create notes but it will not sync.

I haven't changed passwords or updated accounts so I can't work out if this is a mistake I am making or a app issue.

Hope someone can help, cheers.

Comment: Hi commenting on my own topic here. I still have got nothing sorted with this, "reminders" has become "notes" ( I think) but it still will not work, after an update it just freezes on start up, I have reinstalled a few time but doesn't fix issue, it lets me re-enter my evernote synce details but after that freezes again. I saw on product review on Ubuntu store that others are having similiar issues. Has anyone got a fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling the app, deleting the ~/.local/share/com.ubuntu.reminders/ directory, re-installing, and re-authenticating Evernote fixed the issue for me (for now). On Nexus 4 (OTA 9), app version 0.5.472.

I also had success under slightly different condition caused by changing channels by just deleting the directory without any app uninstalling or re-installing. No need to re-authenticate in that case.

You can delete this through the File Manager application on the phone by going into the upper-right hand corner menu item, hitting "unlock full access," entering in your password, then hit the same menu key again, check "Show Hidden Files," navigate to the directory and delete it. You may have to have developer access enabled on the phone to get these options, though I'm not sure.

Using the terminal,the directory can be deleted by running this:

```
rm -R ~/.local/share/com.ubuntu.reminders/
```

in the terminal of the phone, or while in abd shell on your computer. This will delete all locally-saved notes, while those synced with Evernote will be safe with them.

Just in case, you may want to make a copy of the directory first.

Comment: Hey mrm, thanks for comment. Any idea how I go about deleting the  ~/.local/share/com.ubuntu.reminders/ directory I am clueless. I really wanna get this working as it was so handy to use Evernote, really quick way to sync notes/lists etc...

Appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: I've added more detail to the answer above. Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you so much, this worked on the BQ Aquaris E4.5 too. This has been bugging me for about 6 months. I greatly appreciate your help.